# Calling an function that is on an Ionic Angular page from a component in another file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new to both Ionic and Angular and have been struggling to find the solution to my problem. I got a particular function I'd like to call present on a certain page file. I need to call this function from a button component file (in order to execute it on click). I was wondering how to do this as I've tried looking for a solution but can't find one and I can't just copy the function as this reloads some data that needs to be updated in the page. Thank you in advance.

Function on settings.page.ts (the page that contains the function):

```
loadData() {
    this.storageService.getData().then(datas=> {
      if (datas) {
        this.datas = datas;
        for(let data of datas) {
          this.average = this.average + (data.value / data.total);
        }
        this.average = (this.average / datas.length);
        this.average100 = this.average * 100;
      }
    });
```

Where I need to call the function on new-button.component.ts:

```
async showPopover( event ) {
    const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component: NewComponent,
      event: event,
      mode: 'ios'
    });

    await popover.present();
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to add a service. Services allow different components to call the same methods. They are used everywhere in Angular. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific need, you first need to understand how components communication work in angular.

In angular **components are well-defined, encapsulated units** that can communicate with other components **but through proper organized manner**, not just randomly one components calling methods of other component.

You've got a couple of options

1.) You could introduce **EventEmitters** in your calling component and listen to that event in the component that you want to run method on.Provided that your components are linked (parent -> child relationships)

2.) You could move the common code **loadData() method in your case** to an **@Injectable** service and using Dependency Injection introduce it in the **new-button.component.ts** file.

3.) You can use **RxJS Subjects**, call the next method of subject on the button click and this would get listened in any component that has subscribed to the subject.

Please find these few links on the topic

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular

https://medium.com/@manivel45/event-emitter-vs-subject-cross-component-communication-8934376605e1

https://netbasal.com/event-emitters-in-angular-13e84ee8d28c

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions @Obaid, I think EventEmitters will be the way to go as I need the function to stay in the settings page for the sake of simplicity (so it directly updates the data), any suggestions on how to get started or any article you recommend?

Comment: Checked your articles @Obaid, thanks in advanced for those as they were really good, but I can't seem to get it to work as I realized that new-button.component.ts and settings.page.ts are distant relatives (settings.page.ts is the parent of the parent of new-button.component.ts) is anything that I can do? As I said I simply want new-button.component.ts to notify settings.page.ts that there was a change so it can then update the data.